# difference between python file operation modules open and file.

Tags: python

I am working on file operation in python, i found two module,
What is difference between the two file operation module "open" and "file"
functionality wise i found both same.

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python 2.x documentation [says it all](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#file):

> When opening a file, it’s preferable to use `open()` instead of invoking
>   this constructor [`file()`] directly. `file` is more suited to type testing (for
>   example, writing `isinstance(f, file)`).

In Python 3.x, `file` is no longer available.